# Is there a limit on making calls to WordPress.org API's?

Tags: plugin-development, api

I am writing a plugin which makes calls to [https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/{slug}.json](https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/%7Bslug%7D.json)

Is there a limit on making calls to WordPress.org API's? For example once per hour or every 10 minutes etc. 
Read more - https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API#Plugins

Comment: Any suggestions?!

Comment: I guess it is probably easier and faster to ask the wordpress.org people directly.

Comment: @ialocin thanks for the suggestion! So here it is https://wordpress.org/support/topic/is-there-a-limit-on-making-calls-to-wordpressorg-apis?replies=1

Comment: Still relevant today

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if WP API has limits, but, you should always cache your requests every time you deal with a third party API access. it is a good practice to cache the response for an hour or whatever, it will help optimizing the site which will use your plugin, thus it loads faster due to cached responses.

I suggest you use [Transients API « WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API)

Comment: Although what you say is correct, it isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: Apologize to answer rather than to only drop a comment. sorry.

Comment: Not a problem and actually maybe it isn't that bad as additional insight and information, so let it be an answer I guess.